# Find out if an iOS app is compiled with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to find out if an iOS app is compiled with Swift by checking its `.ipa` files?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to know this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Unzip IPA file.
2. Open unzipped package (show content)
3. Open Frameworks folder

[image]

4. You can see swift support libraries inside. That's it!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what i wanted

Comment: @waitianlou so accept the answer if it was helpful